# Property 'type' does not exist on type 'unknown'

Tags: mysql, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am receiving various errors like this after I do

> ionic build --prod --release

```
src/app/pages/top-media/top-media.page.ts:18:16
18   templateUrl: './top-media.page.html',
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component TopMediaPage.


 Error: src/app/pages/top-media/top-media.page.html:106:36 - error TS2339: Property 'type' does not exist on type 'unknown'.

106        <ng-container *ngIf="media?.type==='T'">
```

html

```
     <ion-refresher slot="fixed" (ionRefresh)="topMediaSet($event)">
            <ion-refresher-content pullingIcon="circles" refreshingSpinner="crescent" refreshingText="Refreshing...">
            </ion-refresher-content>
        </ion-refresher>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col class="ion-text-center">
              <ion-button class="media-btn" mode="ios" color="danger" (click)="filter('V')">
                <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="videocam-outline"></ion-icon>
              </ion-button>
            </ion-col>
      
            <ion-col class="ion-text-center">
              <ion-button class="media-btn" mode="ios" color="success" (click)="filter('A')">
                <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="volume-high-outline"></ion-icon>
              </ion-button>
            </ion-col>
      
            <ion-col class="ion-text-center">
              <ion-button class="media-btn" mode="ios" color="tertiary" (click)="filter('T')">
                <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="document-outline"></ion-icon>
              </ion-button>
            </ion-col>
      
            <ion-col class="ion-text-center">
              <ion-button class="media-btn" mode="ios" color="warning" (click)="filter('P')">
                <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="camera-outline"></ion-icon>
              </ion-button>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>

 <ion-row *ngFor="let media of topMedia | filterByType: mediaType | slice:1;  let i = index">
  <ng-container *ngIf="media?.type==='T'">
    {{media?.message | slice:0:2000}}
</p>
```

The problems occurs when i use the filter I created | filterByType: mediaType

ts

```
topMedia:any =[];

mediaType:string = '';


constructor(
...
) { 
  this.topMediaSet();
}


topMediaSet(refresher?:any) {
this.offset = 0;
if (typeof refresher == 'undefined') {
    this.loading = true;
}
this.userData.topMedias(this.offset).pipe(
map((data: any) => {
   if (data.success) {
      this.topMedia = data.topMedia;
   }
   if (typeof refresher != 'undefined') {
            refresher.target.complete();
    }
    this.loading = false;
 })
).subscribe()
}


 filter(mediaType: string) {
  this.mediaType = mediaType;
  console.log(mediaType);
}
```

filter pipe

```
 import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterByType',
})
export class FilterByTypePipe implements PipeTransform {
/**
 * Takes a value and makes it lowercase.
 */
transform(items: any[], type: any): any {

    if (!items) return [];
    if (!type) return items;
    type = type.toLowerCase();
    console.log('type', type);
    return items.filter(it => {
        if (it.type) {
            return it.type.toLowerCase().includes(type);
        }
    });
   }
 }
```

I am getting this error if i put

> filterByType: mediaType |

If I REMOVE THIS LINE FOR THE NGFOR I AM NOT GETTING ANY ERRORS BUT I NEED THE FILTER. Any hint?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Production flags invoke stricter compilers.

`Null` means it doesn't exist.

You are trying to send `null` to a pipe, hence the error message.

Without a working stackblitz reproducing your error, it is challenging to provide an accurate answer, but try adding ngIf to your P tag like so.

This will first test for existence, with null evaluating to false.

```
 <p class="ion-text-wrap" *ngIf="media?.message">
    {{media?.message | slice:0:2000}}
</p>
```

Comment: It's not really a null thing. It was my bad. I am getting errors from properties that are already predefined or set with a value and still getting that error. So, if i put the ngIf condition still it will not make any sense

Answer (score 0):

change

```
topMedia:any =[];
```

to

```
topMedia: Array<any> =[];
```

this should probably solve your problem. but if you know what are you going to put inside the topMedia array, I suggest you define a Media interface and define the array like this:

```
export interface Media{
    message: string;
    ...
}
...
topMedia: Array<Media> =[];
```

And if you are worried about message being null you should check it with `*ngIf` in the container of the message or above that (e.g. like the way **E. Maggini** said)

Comment: This won't change anything otherwise the issue would have manifested before the addition of the production build flag.

Comment: @E.Maggini I just thought that "Property X does not exist on type 'unknown'" should be a type checking problem not a null problem. especially that it's not a runtime error, but a build error. also maybe the issue would have manifested before the addition of the production flag as well as after it and they just haven't tested it without the flag.

Comment: Yes i updated to show that media.type is never null -it always has a value- and i am still getting the error

Comment: @SimonIoa what you add seem to be runtime checking, did you try what I suggested in my answer?

Comment: And what version of Angular and Ionic are you using?

Comment: Ionic 5 Angular 12. Yes i did still the same errors

Comment: What do you mean 'if i know what am i going to put inside'? Iti would be an Object of strings and numbers

Comment: @SimonIoa meaning if you know the keys of the objects and their types, you should define it, that way your code would be cleaner and have less chance of mistake and compiler error. I edited my answer and improved the example.

Comment: I understand Amir but that's not the issue. One last question. if the property is NOT null or undefined and it's predefined and set why it should be unknown? That's what is driving me crazy. What could be the problem?

Comment: the problems occurs with the filter i put on the ngfor without it i am getting no errors.  filterByType: mediaType |  I edited this to show you.

Comment: @SimonIoa Then are you sure you have defined "filterByType" currectly?

Comment: You mean if the pipe is defined? Yes because i use other pipes in pipes.module.ts. If you mean what kind of property is type i don tknow

Answer (score 0):

I got it to show no errors but it doesnt seem to be the correct thing to do. Just a workaround

I replaced

> media.type

to

> media['type']

If someone has a better answer please share. But it did deleted all the errors i was getting after ionic build --prod --release

Comment: in Typescript you can use media?.type, `?.` is the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator